# Can we make pack_all consider only non-null & non-empty columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

`pack_all()` function considers all the input columns while making a dynamic object. Is it possible to somehow force it to consider only non-empty & non-null columns? If not, is there any workaround to apply filter on top of the resulting dynamic value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be added as a new answer, that `pack_all()` did in the meantime get a new option to exclude null/empty values

`pack_all([ignore_null_empty])`

> ignore_null_empty: An optional bool indicating whether to
> ignore null/empty columns and exclude them from the resulting property
> bag. Default: false.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packallfunction

Answer (score 3):

There is no flavor of `pack_all` that will do it, but as an alternative, you can combine `mv-apply` and `mv-expand` operators to achieve this. Here is an example (adapted from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator#applying-mv-apply-to-a-property-bag)):

```
datatable(SourceNumber:string,TargetNumber:string,CharsCount:long)
[
'555-555-1234','555-555-1212',46,
'555-555-1234','555-555-1213',50,
'555-555-1212','',int(null)
]
| extend values =pack_all()
| mv-apply removeProperties = values on 
(
    mv-expand kind = array  values
    | where isempty(values[1])
    | summarize propsToRemove = make_set(values[0])
)
| extend values = bag_remove_keys(values, propsToRemove)
| project-away propsToRemove
```

Comment: thanks, I believe this will be very highly expensive right? Since it tries to process multiple rows (through mv-expand) per actual row.

Comment: I experimented with this , while this works for sure , it is practically not useful option in my situation as it is highly compute expensive. queries end up timing out.

Comment: Is this the last thing that the query is doing? How many records are returned from the query?

Comment: the goal is to then store it in a table from where I intend to export it to azure storage , or directly export. So yes this curated property bag will go as is in the exported data. Also the columns which participate in pack_all themselves are being removed using project-away , only properties column and a few other calculated columns are supposed to exist in the exported data or table.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info, we are looking at adding a new function that will provide this functionality with a better perf, I'll update when it's done.

Comment: also, is it possible to create 2 separate json bags ? say I have columns a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 then one json bag out of a1,a2,a3 and another one out of b1,b2,b3? I guess it's not possible , but this too would have been very useful feature, in general ability to specify columns for pack_all would be an essential feature I would say.

Comment: IIf I understand your question correctly, this should be easy to do, just create two extends, one that packs the a1, a2, a3, second that packs the b1, b2, b3 and then pack both.

Comment: but that's not how pack_all works , we can't specify individual columns to pack_all as arguments , it will work on ALL the columns in the input table (left side of pipe) and not on any selected columns. How do you suggest I specify individual columns to pack_all? In fact what you are suggesting is exactly the feature I was saying it would be good to have.

Comment: What would be the way to specify the names of the columns that should be in each bag? Is that by regular expression or the "*" notation or something else? I suggest that you open a user voice for this and provide an example with the expected function arguments that allows specifying the columns to be included.

Comment: yea I mean as long as there is some way to specify subset of the columns it should have worked for me , either by explicitly specifying individual columns or wild card or regex , but as of now it only takes ALL the columns.

Comment: "explicitly specifying individual columns" works now, using the pack() function (with the added work of specifying the property name), for example, pack("a1",a1, "a2", a2), it seems that what you are asking is a new version of pack() that takes in a list of columns, this will save the need to specify the column name. correct?

Comment: no,pack() won't like that,it does not accept explicit list of columns. e.g. pack(col1,col2) won't work.It expects keys and values to be specified as separate arguments.This is the official syntax:-pack(key1, value1, key2, value2,... ) that's why the first(all the odd arguments)arguments need to be strings because they are treated as keys and all the even arguments are values so they need not be strings. This is a totally different use case than saying pack(col1,col2,col3) and then the keys will be col1,col2,col3 and the corresponding values will actually come from respective column values

Comment: basically we need a version of pack_all() that will work for explicitly specified columns at least (regex, wild cards will be bonus) -- pack() is not column counterpart of pack_all() since its logic , in terms of what it expects as input arguments , is quite different.

Comment: I see. This is a great suggestion, please open a user-voice for it.